# How to find the line number of error in Teradata SQL Assistant

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I'm new to Teradata SQL Assistant and have a simple issue that couldn't find the solution in Terada documentations. [image: I see the below Error]

How I can find the exact location of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the input and find strings that don't conform to your expectations.

For example...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  your_table
WHERE
  TryCast(your_column AS INT) IS NULL
```

https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-Database-SQL-Functions-Operators-Expressions-and-Predicates/March-2017/Data-Type-Conversions/TRYCAST/Syntax-Elements/data_type

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie, This one is very useful and answer my question for this specific example. But is there any way to locate to line of error in Teradata SQL Assistant?

Comment: @MFR - no there is not. If you have cast statements, you can comment them out one at a time to see which specific one is throwing the exception.  Implicit casts can make this harder though.